# How to adjust Font Size according text viewable in a TButton.Text using Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I am using buttons to display product names in a matrix using TGridLayout.

The problem is that commonly Items contains 3 or 4 words and in my language (Portuguese) some words tend to be long.

I would like that somehow I could calculate the size of the font, decreasing it, in order to make all the text show up automatically (of course there is also a decrease limit, anything below 9 or 8 point for the font turn to be difficult to read).

The wordwrap property is turned on to have many lines, and use the most possible space for the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're programming for an Android/iOS app, but you can't change the fontsize of a button. I've had the same problem, my solution was to make an abbreviation of the words. And then i put labels above it to explain the abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can adjust the font size of a button:

```
TButton.TextSettings.Font.Size
```